# opening c# files with visual studio outside of project gives no suggestions

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Im currently writing some very small c# exercises, for a algorithm course.
visual studio is my favourite IDE, and usually, when i create or clone a visual studio project, I get the full functionality of viusal studio including spellchecking and suggestions for fields and methods on objects and so on.

But right now I am just trying to open a single .csc file and write some code in it. The problem is that when i do that, i get no suggestions. So if I create a list I would usually be able to view all the methods and fields inside the list class simply be referencing an object. Syntaxm checking works fine.

How do I turn on intellisense suggestions in a file that is not in a project?

Thank you

Comment: It is normal, to have intellisence you must be in a project in a Visual Studio solution, as I know. Because the editor know nothing about your code and dll's references: it does not know where to search, nothing is loaded and no reflexion is possible. Others editors like some cs shells can offer such functionnalities, but not VS, not the IDE itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is simply to add that file to a project.

1. Open VisualStudio.
2. Create a new project (you can probably use Console project or Class library, depending on what you're doing).
3. Add your file in that project.
4. Make sure your file as the Build Action `C# Compiler`.
   [image]

And that should work.

Comment: that does work, but it also adds a lot of other files, which I find annoying when pushing to git, and every push includes a bunch of config files. Is there really no way of circumventing this?

Comment: That would probably be another question, but you can exclude files or folders from git [using a .gitignore file](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/ignoring-files) at the root of your repo.